# Why Drupal data passed to javascript still the same for all users in diffirent sessions?

Tags: javascript, php, drupal-8

I'm trying to pass data from php to javascript in drupal8.
in my controller, dumping attached data gives different values for each user in each session.
when i console.log this data in javascript, it gives the same data attached for the very first user who logged on the application..

Suppose i'm logged in with user A, the console logs for me data X. When i open new session with user B i expect getting data Y, but i still get the same data X rendered for user A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need a cache for this page?
If not, add options no_cache n the module_name.routing.yml

```
options:
    no_cache: TRUE
```